# TEE TFS CLI on *nix: find and add new files to TFS workspace

Tags: linux, macos, tfs, command-line-interface

I (somewhat awkwardly) use TFS to source-control an iOS project on OS X, and found myself constantly forgetting to add new files (such as new graphic assets) to the workspace before checking in. I use the Eclipse plugin to manage checkouts in general, but it doesn't have any UI for files that aren't yet added to source control (that I've found).

How can I find and add new files without searching my folder heirarchy by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS versions before 2012, you can simply use the `online` command to the TEE Command Line Client, which will scan your local filesystem for changes and pend them.  For example:

```
tf online -adds
```

To detect files that were added on the local filesystem but have not been pended as adds to TFS.

Comment: Wow! Using this, turns out that `tf online -diff -recursive -exclude:xcuserdata` will pick up adds, deletes, _and_ un-checked-out changes!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out this one-liner using the `tf` utility (the CLI piece of TEE):

```
find . -perm +0222 -and -type f -and -not -iname .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0t -L 1 tf add
```

Files that are already added and checked out (or otherwise unlocked) will throw a harmless exception, but new files will be added to the relevant workspace. Run at the root of your local workspace on disk.

(Note: as written, this requires creds to be cached. Either add them yourself, or cache them by adding:

```
export TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS=yes
```

...to your *sh `~/.profile` file. Then, do some mutation operation [such as checkout], providing your creds. TFS will cache them locally.)

---

**Extras:**

If you want to ignore user data for iOS projects specifically (anything in an `xcuserdata` file; it's a huge pain to unlock it / check it out all the time), you can use:

```
find . -name xcuserdata -prune -o -perm +0222 -and -type f -and -not -iname .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0t -L 1 tf add
```

The `-prune` action will ignore any directories (and IIRC, files, technically) and their contents if they are named `xcuserdata`.

Also, you can replace `add` with `checkout` to do this same scan for unlocked files that were not correctly checked out w/ TFS. Same deal: added files and already-checked-out files throw inconsequential exceptions, while sneaky unlocked files get checked out.

Comment: Leaving this for the `TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS` stuff, but don't use this, folks! See @Edward Thomson's answer + my comment on it for a much more effective one-liner.